# Xcode: Custom fonts are not supported in glance or notification interfaces

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, apple-watch

Despite the fact that I can set a custom font to a label from Interface Builder and the label even appears with that font when I launch the app on the Apple Watch simulator, Xcode constantly warns me that

> Custom fonts are not supported in glance or notification interfaces

Is it just another glitch of Xcode 6.3 or I should not use custom fonts on glances and notification interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a glitch. Custom fonts are genuinely not supported anywhere except your main WatchKit app.

Comment: Correct. I've found a [proof](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH19-SW4) of this on the Apple Watch Programming Guide.

Answer (score 1):

For others who might be interested: there is a bug/known issue with IB on XCode 3.x with non-standard fonts and Interface Builder. Custom fonts generally need to be set programatically (via [UIFont fontWithName...)

Comment: Do you mean Xcode 6.3? Xcode 3 would have been a very long time ago.